# SL4A + Intents + Jquery + Webview

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, webview, sl4a

I am writing sl4a android app utilizing webviews. I am trying to achieve a call from the webview to an event handler in my python script that launches an intent to pick an image from the image gallery and send back an image path to the webview so it can append to a pop up screen via foundation 5 reveal module as well as a hidden input tag to submit.

The problem I am having is twofold. I am looking for the correct way to loop the registerCallback function until the user clicks on a photo and returns the value from python i.e. an indefinite amount of time as the user decides which picture to select. As of now, if there is not a sleep or a setTimeout being looped, it is looking for the event before it has happened. Also, the url variable assigned by the anonymous function is not acknowledged as it passes through the if/else statements. I know this has to be a scope issue but I am not certain what I am doing wrong.

**Jquery Code**

```
var picInc = 0;
var url = undefined;

$(function(){
  $('#picSelect').click( function(){
  picInc += 1;
  droid._pickPic();
  while( url == undefined ){
    sleep(3000);   // maybe setTimeout(function{ null function}, 1000);
    droid.registerCallback('picSelect', function(msg){
      url = msg.data;
  });
  }
  if( url == 'None' ){
    url = undefined;
  }else{
    var strip = url.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
  $('.PICADD').append(' /* add img tag with image path */ ');
  url = undefined;
  }
  });
  });
```

**Python Code**

```
while True:
    event = droid.eventWait().result
    name = event['name']
    data = event['data']
    if event['data'] == 'PIC':
        activity = droid.startActivityForResult('android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT', None, 'image/*') #, {'android.intent.action.extra.ALLOW_MULTIPLE': True}
        if activity.result == None:
            droid.eventPost('picSelect', 'None') 
        else:     
            result = activity.result['data']
            parsedUriPath = droid.queryContent(result)
            cleanParsed = parsedUriPath.result[0]['_data']
            droid.eventPost('picSelect', '{}'.format(str(cleanParsed)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not familiar to webView facade in sl4a and below examples are pseudo code.

Did you read https://github.com/kuri65536/sl4a/blob/master/docs/UsingWebView.md ?
This document describe callback function, your code might be:

```
var droid = new Android();
function func_callback(msg) {
  if (msg.data == 'None') {return;}
  $('.PICADD').append(' /* add img tag with image path from msg.data */ ');
}

$(function(){
  droid.registerCallback('pic_select_js', func_callback);
  $('#picSelect').click(function() {
    droid.postEvent("pic_select_py");
  });
});
```

python-side:

```
import android
droid = android.Android()
droid.webViewShow('file:///sdcard/sl4a/scripts/sample.html')
while True:
    droid.waitForEvent('pic_select_py')
    url = "/where/to/pic.png"
    droid.postEvent('pic_select_js', url)
```

BTW, It might be better to remove some logic outside questions.

Comment: This seems like it would work although I found a solution a while back and forgot to post it. Thank you. I also wanted to thank you with your work maintaining the SL4A repository and converting the python build over to PIE so we can get android-python27 working on lollipop and beyond. If you are looking for contributors let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a better way but this worked for me.

It sets a non-blocking loop with setTimeout() to wait for user to select picture from native android gallery and python backend to send back to webview. Anything else would either not catch data on callback as the user did not select a picture yet, blocking js with a sleep function or it would gather data on the next picture select, resulting in the last item selected never being called back to insert into html for submission or view in the custom pop up gallery.

**Jquery**

```
$(function(){
  $('#picSelect').click( function(){
    droid._pickPic();
    waitForElement();
  });
});

function waitForElement(){
  if(typeof uri !== "undefined"){
    if( uri === 'None' ){
      uri = undefined;
      return false;
    }
    else{
      var strip = uri.split('\\').pop().split('/').pop();
      $('#pictures').append(' /* add img tag with image path */ ');
      uri = undefined;
      return true;
    }
  }
  else{
    setTimeout(function(){
        callBack();
        waitForElement();
    }, 1000);
  }
}

function callBack() {
  droid.registerCallback('picSelect', function(msg){
    uri = msg.data;
  });
}
```